Laravel 9 Excel export FromQuery throws error Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string
I am going to implement Laravel 9 with Maatwebsite\Excel. So I made a controller and  export class. There are a lot of rows so I need to use FromQuery implementation.
This is the export class:
<?php

namespace App\Exports;


use App\Models\Customer;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromQuery;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadingRow;


class CustomersXlsExport implements FromQuery
{

    public function query()
    {
        return Customer::query()->where('id', '<', 5);
    }
}

and this is the controller
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Exports;

use App\Exports\CustomersXlsExport;
use App\Http\Controllers\JsonController;
use Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\BinaryFileResponse;

/**
 * @group CustomersExport
 *
 * CustomerExportController
 */
class CustomerExportController extends JsonController
{

    /**
     * Store customers XLS
     * @endpoint GET /exports/customers
     *
     */
    public function index(): BinaryFileResponse|JsonResponse
    {
        try {
            Excel::store(new CustomersXlsExport, 'customers.xls', 'local', null);
            return $this->sendJsonResponse(......);
        }
        catch (\Throwable $e) {
            Log::error($e->getMessage(), ['prevMessage' => $e->getPrevious()?->getMessage(), 'trace' => $e->getTrace()]);
            return $this->sendJsonResponse(......);
        }
    }
}

If I use FromCollection method everything works fine. But I can not. The FromQuery always throws me an error  Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string. Always whatever method I use like download(), raw() or store(). I dont understand it.
Can somebody tell me please what is going on here?
